# Find string and replace line

Tags: python-3.x

I already could get a lot of my code together (although it is not a long code). However i am struggeling to achieve the "replace the whole line and not only the search term". Is there like a symbol you can place to do that? Like: * or % etc.

```
import glob
for files in glob.glob("./prtr/*p*"):
    with open(files, 'r') as file:
        filedata = file.read()
        filedata = filedata.replace('TCPOPTS', 'TCPOPTS  = 80\n')
        with open(files, 'w') as file:
            file.write(filedata)
```

It works so far that "TCPOPTS" is replaced with "TCPOPTS   = 80" and a linebreak is done. But it is not deleting the rest of that line but just moves it to the next line. Which is of course correct due the code. So as mentioned all i need now is to have it not replace the search term but the whole line containing that search term.

Any advice is highly apreciated :)

Kind regards

Edit:

Before:

```
TCPOPTS = 90
```

Afterwards:

```
TCPOPTS = 80
  = 90
```

Expected:

```
TCPOPTS = 80
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the text and expected output?

Comment: I updated my posting with the requested information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently solved a very similar task in the following way:

```
# Scan file
with open(filePath, 'r') as file:
    fileContent = file.readlines()

# Find line, where modification should be done
for lineIndex in range(len(fileContent)):

    if ('TCPOPTS' in fileContent[lineIndex]):
        fileContent[lineIndex] = 'TCPOPTS  = 80\n'

        with open(filePath, 'w') as tableFile:
            tableFile.writelines(fileContent)

        break
```

The benefit of doing it this way is, that the file is not rewritten, if your keyword is not found.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked perfectly. Your code is starting from my code at the third line. I just had to replce "filepath" with "files" due my code defines that in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.startswith`

**Ex:**

```
import glob
for files in glob.glob("./prtr/*p*"):
    res = []
    with open(files) as infile:                
        for line in infile:                         #Iterate Each line
            if line.startswith("TCPOPTS"):          #Check if TCPOPTS in line
                res.append("TCPOPTS = 80\n")
            else:
                res.append(line)

    with open(files, "w") as outfile:                #Write back to file.
        for line in res:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: I tried your code and although i see it runs through unfortunately there are no changes in the file.

Comment: is this on a single line `TCPOPTS = 90` ?

Comment: yes, in the original source it is on a single line. I added \n so if there are lines afterwards, there is no issue that two lines become one.

Comment: Can you put a `print` after `if line.startswith("TCPOPTS"):` to see if it is picking up the string?

Comment: Small change in your code and it works like a charm. <pre> if line.startswith( 'TCPOPTS' ): <code>

Comment: If you can update your code I can mark your answer as "accepted answer" as it is working as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` (after importing `re`) to match the whole line and use back-references to preserve selective portions of the match:

Change:

```
filedata = filedata.replace('TCPOPTS', 'TCPOPTS  = 80\n')
```

to:

```
filedata = re.sub(r'^(?P<header>TCPOPTS\s*=\s*).*', r'\g<header>80', filedata, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: As I test this, it gives me this error message:
`code` re.error: invalid group reference 18 at position 1

Comment: Oops I did not notice that in this case the backreference is followed by a number, so the number gets considered as part the backrefrence. I've updated my answer to use a named group instead.

Comment: Well code is executed without errors now. Thanks. But there are no changes in the files. I can see they were accessed, but nothing changed.